# Incoorect Count Results

Tags: oracle, analytic-functions

I have two data tables Employees and Departments. I want to show the number of employees in each department, the average of salaries in each department, among other things. The code I have is:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name, count(e.last_name) Employees,
avg(e.salary) Avg_Salary, e.last_name, e.salary, e.job_id
from departments d, employees e
where d.department_id = e.department_id
group by d.department_id, d.department_name, e.last_name, e.salary, e.job_id
order by d.department_id;
```

This code runs fine, but the results for the employee count and average salary are not what I am looking for. My results are:

```
Department_ID Department_Name Employees Avg_Salary Last_Name Salary Job_ID
------------- --------------- --------- ---------- --------- ------ ------
10            Administration  1         4400       Whalen    4400   AD_ASST
20            Marketing       1         6000       Fay       6000   MK_REP
20            Marketing       1         13000      Hartstein 13000  MK_MAN
```

As you can see, the Employees count display 1 for each employee, not the total in each department; and the Avg_Salary is the same as Salary, not the actual salary average in each department.

This is the results I want:

```
 Department_ID Department_Name Employees Avg_Salary Last_Name Salary Job_ID
-------------  --------------- --------- ---------- --------  ------ ------
10             Administration  1         4400       Whalen    4400   AD_ASST
20             Marketing       2         9500       Fay       6000   MK_REP
20             Marketing       2         9500       Smith     13000  MK_MAN
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it - using analytic functions:

```
select d.department_id, d.department_name,
       count(e.last_name) over (partition by d.department_id) Employees,
       avg(e.salary) over (partition by d.department_id) Avg_Salary,
       e.last_name, e.salary, e.job_id
from departments d, employees e
where d.department_id = e.department_id
order by d.department_id;
```